# Pegar todos níveis de categorias dos produtos

Tags: mysql, sql

estou com uma dúvida. Tenho uma tabela de categorias:

```
CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lft` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rght` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publicado` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `icon` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

E uma tabela de produtos:

```
CREATE TABLE `produtos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `categoria_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Onde produtos.categoria_id é uma chave estrangeira da tabela de categorias.
A tabela de categorias tem categorias e subcategorias, sendo que categorias.parent_id faz referência a um categoria.id para indicar que é filha da mesma.

Preciso exportar a tabela de produtos com um JOIN pegando 3 primeiros níveis das categorias, e não sei qual função utilizar para melhor adequação.

Resultado deve estar:
NOME PRODUTO - ID PRODUTO - NOME CATEGORIA NÍVEL 1 - NOME CATEGORIA NÍVEL 2 - NOME CATEGORIA NÍVEL 3 - DATA

Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, o produto sempre será relacionado com o terceiro nível ? Veja se te ajuda o seguinte código:

```
SELECT
p.titulo,
p.id,
n1.nome AS cat1,
n2.nome AS cat2,
n3.nome AS cat3
FROM produtos p
INNER JOIN categorias n3 ON n3.id = p.categoria_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN categorias n2 ON n2.id = n3.parent_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN categorias n1 ON n1.id = n2.parent_id
```

Comment: Sensacional, Rovann. Isso mesmo, muito obrigado!